# how to make a JQuery Object contains a snapshot of Dom Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found that a JQuery object contains a pointer to a DOM object, and the context of the Jquery object would change with the HTML being modified. However, I'd like to record Logs and I don't want the Jquery Object in the history records to change, what should I do?

Comment: I construct another object containing attribute I need, to solve the problem, but I stil want to know if there any method to solve this problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery clone function:
https://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
var original = $('selector');
var copy = original.clone();
```

Now if you change original, the copy won't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery object contains an internal list of DOM object references.  These are merely reference to actual DOM objects in the page, not copies of anything.  So, if the page content changes in those DOM objects, then the jQuery object will still refer to the same DOM objects that now have the updated content.

If you want to save some content from the DOM so it won't change if the DOM changes, then you have to copy that content from the DOM objects, either into some new DOM objects that you create or just into other Javascript variables.